# Jquery simplyscroll trigger pause/unpause

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm almost ready to pull my hair out. For the life of me I cannot force this to pause. Yes, the script offers a pause button. I've looked through the code and found the bit where it fires the pause. with that said i still cannot get it to pause! Like I said I know it provides a pause button but I don't need the physical button within the element.

If anyone can help the actual pause button example is here (http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/pause.html). Just remember I don't need the button. I just need to be able to pause/unpause which I know is supported but I was hoping someone could show me how to trigger it. Obviously the ways i've tried haven't worked.

I could almost bet I've been close to the solution. I've tried so many things. Any help is appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: The entire script it located here.... Not sure what you want. My code doesn't work LOL
https://raw.github.com/logicbox/jquery-simplyscroll/master/jquery.simplyscroll.js

All I want to do is pause/unpause the scroller manually.

Comment: Show ur tried code .. all u share is simplescroll jquery code. What is ur html/css/js look like ??

Comment: LOL Why would you need my code. simplyscoll is a function. THAT IS WHY I POSTED THE SOURCE. You don't need my code. All I am looking for is a way to trigger the pause/unpause manually WITHOUT the button....

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to pause it bcaz JS plugin is not exposing any method for it. 
But there is a hack which can use to pause the scroll.. There is class at pause button u can use it explicit to call click  as per ur cond.

```
 $(document).ready( function (){
   $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
     pauseButton: true
  });
  $(".simply-scroll-btn-pause").hide();  
 });
function pause()
 {
     $(".simply-scroll-btn-pause").click();
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w84Bn/2/)

Comment: Darn, I had something real similar and it didn't work. The only difference from your solution and what I need to trigger the pause WITHOUT a click. I was trying to use tigger() to get that to work but I was failing. Maybe the button needs to be enabled before I can trigger the click to pause it.... I will try what you posted with my variation.

All I am trying to do is pause the scrollers when they are out of sight (viewport).

I did notice a togglePause() function in the file but still can't find a way to utilize it...

Thanks for your time @Neha